# Graph API - use variable in filter query

Tags: azure, api, rest, azure-active-directory, microsoft-graph-api

I am calling the Microsoft Graph API's to import user details into an application (which uses REST based connector) from Azure AD.

The application provides a variable (xyz) to be used in order to do incremental user imports.

I need to pass the application variable as ${xyz}. The Graph query seems to be confused about the $ symbol and is throwing an illegal character exception for the $ sign.

Below is the GET query used :

"https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/users?$select=id,displayName,userPrincipalName,mail,accountEnabled,onPremisesLastSyncDateTime&$count=true&$filter=onPremisesLastSyncDateTime%20ge%20${xyz}"

Error : *[22;39mjava.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Illegal character in query at index 182:*

Have tried to use $$, single quotes,backslash,` etc. to fix the issue, but none worked. Any help would be much appreciated.

Comment: Doesn't look like an error coming from Graph - you have a Java error. Do you actually substitute real data for the placeholder?

Comment: Have tried with real data and it has worked for me. Below is an example :

https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/users?$select=id,displayName,userPrincipalName,mail,accountEnabled,onPremisesLastSyncDateTime&$count=true&$filter=onPremisesLastSyncDateTime%20ge%202021-07-12T08:57:04Z

The application converts the Variable into a real value during the runtime

Answer (score 0):

As @Dmitry Streblechenko suggested, the error indicates that the variable does not have any real data.

If the real data is passed to the variable, the Graph API call runs successfully